# Spinnaker:I could not configure spinnaker on aws

Tags: spinnaker

i try to install and configure spinnaker on aws with 4 cores and 16 GB RAM. but i could not do it since there is no clear documentation about spinnaker. Could anyone help me with this

Comment: Can you offer a bit more information on what happened when you tried to install? There is a small bit of details on the GitHub page: https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker

Comment: I have installed spinnaker in aws using 4 cores and 16 GB ram 
and  created spinnaker roles and policies as per the  document  by http://www.spinnaker.io/.
After i launch the instance it creates two more servers automatically by the name bastionServer and spinnakerWebService
and i have entered the spinnaker server which i created using putty and started the spinnaker service
but when i give http://127.0.0.1:9000, the desk UI is not showing

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty extensive documentation here: http://www.spinnaker.io/docs - if you're having a specific issue after looking through the installation documentation here, you can join the Slack channel (http://join.spinnaker.io/) and likely get help with whatever problems you're running into.

Comment: But it is not sufficient and the configuration in spinnaker is not given